# How do I upload a file in in NestJs. Passing an array of DTO and a single file in each of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, multer

I'm working on a Nestjs file upload API and I have the controller method for upload as follows

```html
@Post('file/upload')
      @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Controller API to upload file to S3 bucket' })
      @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
      @CommonHeaders()
      @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files', 5, {
          fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
              if (!file.originalname.match(/^.*\.(png|pdf|csv|txt|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|msg|hbs)$/))
                  cb(new HttpException(ERROR_CONSTANTS['E1084'], 400), false)
              else if (parseInt(req.headers["content-length"]) > 1024 * 1024 * 20 /* 20 MB */)
                  cb(new HttpException(ERROR_CONSTANTS['E1090'], 400), false)
              else
                  cb(null, true)
          },
      }), DocHandlerValidationInterceptor)
      async uploadFile(
          @UploadedFiles(new FileValidationPipe) files: Array<Express.Multer.File>,
          @ADUser() user: AzureUser, @Body() request: DocHandlerDTO) {
            try {
              return await this.docHandlerService.uploadFileToS3(files, user, request);
            }
            catch(exception: any) {
              return exception;
            }
          }
```

The request body DocHandlerDTO is as follows

```html
/** Input arguments for querying the DocHandler Collection */
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsOptional, MaxLength, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
export class DocHandlerDTO {
    @ApiProperty()
    @MaxLength(15)
    applicationName: string;
    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @IsOptional()
    @MaxLength(100)
    itemId: string;
    @ApiProperty()
    @MaxLength(100)
    category: string;
    @ApiProperty({type: Boolean, default: true, required: false})
    active: boolean;
    @ApiProperty({format: 'binary'})
    files: Array<Express.Multer.File>;
}
```

Everything is working as expected, But I need a requirement to update my DTO structure as follows

```html
/** Input arguments for querying the DocHandler Collection */
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsOptional, MaxLength, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
class DocDetailDTO {
    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @IsOptional()
    @MaxLength(100)
    itemId: string;
    @ApiProperty()
    @MaxLength(100)
    category: string;
    @ApiProperty({type: Boolean, default: true, required: false})
    active: boolean;
    @ApiProperty({format: 'binary'})
    file: Express.Multer.File;
}
export class DocHandlerDTO {
    @ApiProperty()
    @MaxLength(15)
    applicationName: string;
    @ApiProperty({type: DocDetailDTO, isArray: true})
    @ValidateNested()
    doc_details: DocDetailDTO[];
}
```

In new DTO, the files field changed to single file and it moved to the DocDetailDTO. The parent DTO(DocHandlerDTO) is having array of DocDetailDTO.

But I'm unable to figure out the changes that needs to be done in the controller method to accommodate my new DTO structure. What are the changes needs to be done in FilesInterceptor and UploadFiles decorators.

Comment: First, in both `DocHandlerDTO` implementations, it seems wrong, as there should not be `file` or `files` keys in your DTO because they simply do not exist there. You get the files from the interceptor. You might want to verify it, check whether `request.files` in the first implementation is `undefined` or no